# httpClient get vs request

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I'm migrating my app from HttpModule to HttpClientModule, and I'm having trouble with HttpRequest.

I'm not able to get an answer using HttpRequest, but I got it with "get", this code works and returns the data:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

export class myClass {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public get<T>(options?: Object): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get<T>('https://swapi.co/api/people/1', options);
 }
}


//from anotherFile:

return this.myClass.get()
```

and the same code changing get return to:

```
 return this.httpClient.request<T>(new HttpRequest('GET', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1', options));
```

It fails and returns.

```
{type: 0}type: 0__proto__: Object
```

what are I'm doing grong with HttpRequest?

Comment: define a strict type to `T` and pass that interface to it

Comment: I tried it but I got the same, I guess my problem is in HttpRequest

Comment: Why do you use `request`? Why don't you try to use `get` itselt? Less code, nicer code

Comment: @cucuru can you create a working example using a plunker or a stackblitz

Comment: M98 you are right, I was thinking as old api, but not the new one, I'll use get, thanks!

Comment: You have to pass a T parameter or define a default in the method